# Angular Material Sort and paginator not displaying

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am finalizing a project in angular using material. Everything works fine except for the sorting and paginator functions. I added the code from the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), but when I test it in my browser, the little arrows appear and they work (I don't get any error messages). Why is it not working?

(My data is stored on a database)

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name" >
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Amount </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.amount}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator color="accent" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

TypeScript

```
 import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
 import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
 import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';

 export class ExpenseComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{

  constructor() {}

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'amount'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.expense);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use a service to get the data. In subscribe function to your service you give value to dataSource, dataSource.paginator and dataSource.sort

Comment: Do you have an example? I have a service which uses Dexie

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you has a service, don't import what feed the service, only has a function that return an observable with the data

```
getData()
{
    return this.httpClient.get(....)
}
```

Then in your component you has

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'amount'];
  dataSource:MatTableDataSource;

  subscription:any;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;


  constructor(dataService:DataService){}

  ngOnInit()
  {
       this.subscription=this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res:any)=>{
           //is in subscribe function where you create the dataSource
           this.dataSource=new MatDataSource(res)
           this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
           this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

       })
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```